# "NSL" meaning in XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt, soa

I am new to XSL files, and I am having some trouble deciphering what the following piece of code is doing. I have searched the internet and cannot find anything to  tell me what "nsl" means exactly. 
Could someone please shed some light on this for me? 
This is part of a SOA system.

```
                <xsl:when test='ns1:Payment/ns1:PaymentHeader/ns1:ConsolidationType = "STANDARD"'>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns1:Payment/ns1:PaymentModeDetail/ns1:GenericDetail/ns1:GenericLineItem">
                       <ns0:ApInvoiceLinesInterface>
                          <ns0:invoiceLineId>
                             <xsl:value-of select="oraext:sequence-next-val('AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE_S',$CONN)"/>
                          </ns0:invoiceLineId>
                          <xsl:choose>
                             <xsl:when test="ns1:CommonInvoiceLineElements/ns1:AdjustmentReasonGid/ns1:Gid/ns1:Xid!=''">                                 
                                <ns0:lineTypeLookupCode>
                                   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">MISCELLANEOUS</xsl:text>
                                </ns0:lineTypeLookupCode>
                             </xsl:when>
                             <xsl:otherwise>
                                <ns0:lineTypeLookupCode>
                                   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">FREIGHT</xsl:text>
                                </ns0:lineTypeLookupCode>
                             </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                          <ns0:amount>
                             <xsl:value-of select="ns1:CommonInvoiceLineElements/ns1:FreightRate/ns1:FreightCharge/ns1:FinancialAmount/ns1:MonetaryAmount"/>
                          </ns0:amount>
                          <ns0:description>
                             <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring-after(../../../ns1:PaymentHeader/ns1:InvoiceRefnum[ns1:InvoiceRefnumQualifierGid/ns1:Gid/ns1:Xid="INVOICE_DESCRIPTION"]/ns1:InvoiceRefnumValue,"BNM."),ns1:CostTypeGid/ns1:Gid/ns1:Xid)'/>
                          </ns0:description>
                          <ns0:taxClassificationCode>
                             <xsl:value-of select='concat(../../../ns1:PaymentHeader/ns1:VatAnalysis/ns1:VatCodeGid/ns1:Gid/ns1:Xid,"%")'/>
                          </ns0:taxClassificationCode>
                          <ns0:distCodeConcatenated>
                             <xsl:value-of select="ns1:CommonInvoiceLineElements/ns1:GeneralLedgerGid/ns1:Gid/ns1:Xid"/>
                          </ns0:distCodeConcatenated>
                       </ns0:ApInvoiceLinesInterface>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </xsl:when>
```

The are which in which I would like to understand most is:

```
<ns0:amount>
  <xsl:value-of select="ns1:CommonInvoiceLineElements/ns1:FreightRate/ns1:FreightCharge/ns1:FinancialAmount/ns1:MonetaryAmount"/>
</ns0:amount>
```

My reason for wanting an understanding of this, is because I believe the following segment of code with this block is returning a positive value for the number when there is a negative number passed to it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not `nsl`, but `ns1` with a one as last character. I have no time for a full answer, unfortunately, but look for "XML namespaces". Those namespaces can also be used in XPath queries (the stuff inside `select=""`).

Comment: "I have searched the internet..." You need to find a more effective learning strategy. If you don't know that ns1 is a namespace prefix, then the internet isn't going to tell you. Reading a book about XPath (or even reading the W3C specification) would give you the answer a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

`ns1` is a prefix used to select elements that are in a namespace. Somewhere in your stylesheet there is a namespace declaration binding this prefix to a namespace URI, in the form of:

```
xmlns:ns1="some/string"
```

Somewhere in your source XML there is a similar namespace declaration placing some or all of its elements in this namespace. You need to use a prefix bound to the same namespace URI in order to select the elements in this namespace.

> I believe the following segment of code with this block is returning a
>   positive value for the number when there is a negative number passed
>   to it.

I see no basis for such belief. Why don't you post a (minimized) example showing the problem.